# Approximation of poly of degree 4 by degree 2

Tags: numerical-methods, error-function, interpolation-theory

Let $(x)=x^4$ be approximated by a polynomial of degree less or equal to 2, which interpolates $x^4$ at x = -1,0,1then the maximum absolute interpolation error over the interval[-1,1] is equal to?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

You have three points on $f(x)=x^4$.  Find a quadratic $g(x)$ that passes throught these three points.  Then you are looking for $\max |f(x)-g(x)|$.  Compute it as a function of $x$, take the derivative, set to zero ...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please explain why we are looking for max | $f(x)$ - g(x) |

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please explain why we are looking for $\max |f(x)-g(x)|$ .

Comment: Because that is the maximum error between $x^4$ and your quadratic.